# Problema con linear-gradient en Chrome y Opera

Tags: html, css, webservice

Estoy intentando hacer lo que se ve en la imagen
[image: Correcto]

En firefox funciona bastante bien, pero en Opera y Chrome se ve asi
[image: Incorrecto]

Este es mi codigo

````css
```
   #whatwedo{
   position: absolute;
   top: 30%;
   left: 30%;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2860A7, #004284);
   background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   width: 60%;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: 'Lemon/Milk', sans-serif;
   font-style: bold;
   text-align: center;
   }
```
````

```html
<label id="whatwedo">Equipo de soporte especializado las 24 horas de los 7 días de la semana</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que se esta guardando el `css` en el `cache` del navegador. En los otros navegadores no se muestra por que tienes la propiedad: `display: none;`.

Prueba realizando un hard reload en el navegador que en firefox y chrome es con el shorcut `ctrl` + `shift` + `r`.

Comment: Sucede lo mismo, y disculpa, el display:none; no va en el codigo ahora lo edito

Comment: Tienes asignado el valor del color del texto a transparente. `-webkit-text-fill-color`

Comment: Si lo quito el gradiente bordea el texto, no se sobrepone con el degradado